# How to use multimetric python library for calculating code parameters?

Tags: python, code-metrics

I am working on project which deals with calculation of halsted matrix and mccabe cyclomatic complexity for the codes in various languages. I found this library multimeric but its documentation is not intuitive. Please explain to me how to use this library for finding code metrics.
if you know any other library which does this work then please suggest.

Comment: If you mean [this multimetric](https://github.com/priv-kweihmann/multimetric), you'd better ask the author directly. I don't think it has many users at this point.

Answer (score 1):

install multimetric follow the instruction from PyPI. go to the code(example.py) location. e.g. cd /user/Desktop/code
Then type these in terminal:
multimetric example.py
then you can see the result.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you are asking a question. The only reason that I have edited this into an answer is that somebody seems to have seen an answer in this.... Please [edit] to make sure the answering part is what you meant. For the questioning part (which I deleted) please create your own question by using the "Ask Question" button.